# How to properly connect the bluetooth server in C for Android?

Tags: android, c, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect an application between the computer and an android app. The app will be the client and the computer will be the server.

Using BlueZ (C library for bluetooth on linux) for server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    // allocate socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);

    // accept one connection
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    // read data from the client
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }

    // close connection
    close(client);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The source of this example is : http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

And the class of the app that i'm using to connect is:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.UUID; 

public class ConnectionThread extends Thread {


    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    BluetoothServerSocket btServerSocket = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    String btDevAddress = null;
    String myUUID = "00000101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9C34BF";
    boolean server;
    boolean running = false;
    public ConnectionThread() {

        this.server = true;
    }
    public ConnectionThread(String btDevAddress) {

        this.server = false;
        this.btDevAddress = btDevAddress;
    }
    public void run() {

        this.running = true;
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(this.server) {
            try {
                btServerSocket = btAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Super Bluetooth", UUID.fromString(myUUID));
                btSocket = btServerSocket.accept();
                if(btSocket != null) {

                    btServerSocket.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
            }


        } else {

            try {

                BluetoothDevice btDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btDevAddress);
                btSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(myUUID));

                btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                if (btSocket != null)
                    btSocket.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
            }

        }

        if(btSocket != null) {

            toMainActivity("---S".getBytes());

            try {
                input = btSocket.getInputStream();
                output = btSocket.getOutputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytes;

                while(running) {

                    bytes = input.read(buffer);
                    toMainActivity(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, bytes));

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
            }
        }

    }
    private void toMainActivity(byte[] data) {

        Message message = new Message();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putByteArray("data", data);
        message.setData(bundle);
        MainActivity.handler.sendMessage(message);
    }
    public void write(byte[] data) {

        if(output != null) {
            try {

                output.write(data);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
        }
    }


    public void cancel() {

        try {

            running = false;
            btServerSocket.close();
            btSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        running = false;
    }
}
```

To send a data to the server I do:

```
ConnectionThread connect = new ConnectionThread(data.getStringExtra("Address_server"));
connect.start();
byte[] data = "20".getBytes();
connect.write(data);
```

The problem is not that the connection is occurring. I believe it's because the server is out of UUID.

How can I insert the UUID into the server so that it can receive the data sent?

Answer (score 2):

This question may be slightly old, but seeing as I faced the same problem recently, I want to share one possible solution I came up with.  The solution is essentially two projects (skeletal examples): a CMake project (Linux side) and an Android Studio project (APK).  To avoid sharing winded explanations, I'll embed the [Github repository here](https://github.com/edisonslightbulbs/rfcomm). Im open to questions should the need arise, and good luck to the next person who tackles this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in libbluetooth/raw socket based. But you can use profile manager interface provided by Bluez to create your own custom profile and register this with bluetoothd.

Below is the sample slide directly copied from [this presentation](http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Bluetooth%20on%20Modern%20Linux_0.pdf).

[image: Profile Manager]

To explain in detail, you need to define the methods described in [Profile1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n108) interface and register it with Bluetoothd using "[RegisterProfile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n12)" method.

I don't have any custom profile implementation example, but you can always refer [bluez-alsa repository](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa) for AG/HFP/HS based profile implementations, which is implemented as external profiles using this interface.

Most interesting part for you in this repository is, "[register_profile](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa/blob/master/src/bluez.c#L886)" API, which take UUID and other required parameters. You can copy the same implementation and register your own UUID and implement,

[NewConnection](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n119): Action which needs to be performed when new device is connected with server. You can find how to connect using DBUS in Linux [here](https://gist.github.com/parthitce) with explanation [here](https://www.linumiz.com/category/blog/).

[RequestDisconnection](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n132): Which will be called by Bluetoothd when device is disconnected. You can perform cleanup for device based allocation/resources.

[Release](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n111): Which will be called when Bluetoothd exits. You can perform the profile complete cleanup and [UnregisterProfile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n95) for graceful exit.